# how to play Youtube video in ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, youtube, video-streaming

I have a Sample Design.
[image: Click Here to view the Sample Pic]

Like the same, exact I need to View the video in my ViewController.
I have tried with WebView but video player controls are different.
If someone Familiar with it, Help me pls!

Comment: Refer this link : https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper

Comment: you can use UIWebView or MPMoviePlayerController to play youtube video

Comment: @PiyushPatel i have tried that library too, but i have ended up with a different Controls.Like buttons with white tint which is different from my sample Design.

Comment: So what have you done so far? represent your code

Comment: @Vicky_Vignesh you can go through this library also:-https://github.com/hellozimi/HCYoutubeParser

Comment: @Fay007 this is the Code i have been Followed 
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper

Answer (score 2):

**Take Web View outlet**

```
 @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!  //Web View Outlet
```

**Add Below Code In ViewDidLoad**

```
 webView.delegate = self

 let url = "http://yoururl.com/videoname.extension" //Your URL Formate
 let urlStringModified :String = urlString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())! //For Adding Percentage in URL Formate to Getting Actual URL Value
 let searchURL : NSURL = NSURL(string: urlStringModified)! //Convert String to NSURL
 let urlReq = NSURLRequest(URL: searchURL) //Convert NSURL to NSURLRequest
 webView.loadRequest(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below link to play you tube Video

Since youtube now uses v3 of its api, here is a new link with the oficial instructions: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper

Answer (score 0):

@Fay007 @amit Varma @Piyush Patel

This is what I get from this link from youtube 
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKZhP.png)

See the controls, it is different from what I wanted.